# Word Count of a file using String Arrays (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, count, split, cpu-word

```
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String thisline = scan.nextLine();
        totalnumber.countthelines++; //linecount works
             for(int i = 0; i < thisline.length();i++){
                  totalnumber.charactercounter++;  //chararacter count works
                  String [] thewords = thisline.split (" ");
                  totalnumber.wordcounter = thewords.length;  //does not work
             }
        }
```

I am having trouble getting my wordcounter to work(I am already able to count the characters and lines). I have tried many different ways to make it work, but it always ends up only counting the words from the last line of the read in file. Any suggestions on how to make it read every single line instead of just the last? 
Thanks

Comment: Don't ask questions and then later remove your code. I have fixed your 2 questions you did this in. STOP!!!

Answer (score 2):

Well :

```
totalnumber.wordcounter += thewords.length
```

should be enough !

You just forgot to *add* the number of words...
So the entiere code is :

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String thisline = scan.nextLine();
    totalnumber.countthelines++; //linecount works
    totalnumber.charactercounter+=thisline.length();  //chararacter count works
    String [] thewords = thisline.split (" ");
    totalnumber.wordcounter += thewords.length; 
    }
```

(Sorry about the multiple edits. Sometime, it's so obvious... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
String [] thewords = thisline.split (" ");
totalnumber.wordcounter += thewords.length;
```

outside of the loop iterating the characters. Note the `+=` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < thisline.length(); i++) {
    totalnumber.charactercounter++;  //chararacter count works
}

String [] thewords = thisline.split (" ");
totalnumber.wordcounter = thewords.length;  //does not work
```